# The commutator of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

> The commutator [X, Y] of two matrices is defined by the equation
>
> $$\begin{align} [X, Y] = XY − YX. \end{align}$$
>
> Two anti-commuting matrices A and B satisfy
>
> $$\begin{align} A^2=I \quad B^2=I \quad [A,B]=2iC. \end{align}$$
>
> (a) Prove that $C^2=I$ and that $[B,C] = 2iA$.

I'm thinking how to prove $C^2=I$.

By proving $[A,B]^2=-4I$ we can conclude that $C^2=I$.

\begin{align}
(AB - BA)(AB - BA) =\\
= ABAB - ABBA - BAAB + BABA =\\
= ABAB + BABA - 2I
\end{align}

Is $ABAB = -I$ ? Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ anti-commute, then it follows
\begin{align}
ABAB = -AABB = -I.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness I'll show the second part of the question:
$$
[B,C]=BC-CB=B(-iAB)-(-iAB)B= \\ =-iBAB+iABB=-iBAB+iA=iABB+iA= \\ =iA+iA=2iA.
$$

Where it is used $AB=iC$ since $[A,B]=2AB$.