# What does this notation $[A, B]$ means for matrices?

Tags: matrices, notation

The question came in Chemistry exam. [image]

Does anyone know what does notation $[A, B]$ stands for? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory
Most likely it stands for $AB- BA$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002524/the-commutator-of-two-matrices

Comment: The chemistry class certainly has a list of references. Please open a book from this list for the course. I am sure it is defined there. Then the question is easy to answer (also mentioned in such a book).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am Maths student only :) Someone sent me this.

Comment: Even better! Then take any book on Lie algebras. The first example is that the matrix algebra $M_n(K)$ is a Lie algebra with the commutator Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$. Or just search the term $[A,B]$ in the web.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure sir. Any recommendation from your side.

Comment: Yes, I knew you would "believe" this as a "Believer".